# Is jacobian matrix of a function is the direction of descent?

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, jacobian, gradient-descent

Since the gradient of a function shows the steepest descent direction, can I assume that the jacobian matrix of a function implies the direction of steepest descent in case of multiobjective optimization? In that case if I have the Jacobian of more than one function and if I want to calculate a common descent direction for both the functions, then should I add both the jacobian matrices and consider it as the direction of steepest descent for both the functions?

Comment: Descent is defined only for scalar valued functions. The Jacobian is a matrix (not just a vector) for a vector valued function. Think about this and rationalize your question.

Comment: By Jacobian I mean first order partial derivative of the function. Does it shows the descent direction of a function? The gradient shows the direction of steepest descent right?

Comment: Could you please elaborate where I am going wrong here? For example how will you find the direction of steepest descent in case of a multivariate function? I dont understand why there is a downvote on this question without any comments or info?

Comment: That's my point. Even that machinery cannot find the impossible.

Comment: what do you mean by machinery? Which machine are you referring to here? @KurtG.

Comment: What made you think that we can speak about the *descent* of the function $f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ when we go from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ ?

Comment: I could imagine it as a descent in 2 dimension. The function can be minimized by gradient descent in 2D vector space. But we need the partial order derivative of the function to determine the direction. Yes or No? @KurtG.

Comment: What is the minimum of, say, $f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x^2+y^2\\x^{-2}+y^{-2}\end{pmatrix}$? More importantly: how would you *define* this ?

Comment: You edited the Question to introduce the phrase "multiobjective optimization".  I think it could be a step forward in helping you understand that a definition needs to be introduced as well.  Perhaps something along the lines of a direction in which *all* components of a vector-valued function are decreasing.  But it needs to be spelled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of
$$
\|f\|=\sqrt{f_1^2+...+f_n^2}
$$
is the vector
$$
\nabla\|f\|=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\nabla f_k}{\|f\|}
$$
and gives the direction of the steepest [**ascent**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202163/problem-with-proof-gradient-steepest-ascent) of $\|f\|\,.$
Since the vector $\nabla f_k=(\partial_1 f_k,...,\partial_mf_k)$ is the $k$-th row of the Jacobian matrix $J$ of $f$ it turns out that the vector $\nabla\|f\|$ is the matrix vector product
$$
\nabla\|f\|=\frac{J^\top f}{\|f\|}\,.
$$

Comment: Thats a great answer! It is really very helpful. So we can say that each row i.e kth row of the Jacobian is the steepest descent direction for the kth function.

Comment: For the $k$-th function $f_k$. What bothered me during the last few hours was that the notion of minimizing the function $(f_1,...,f_n)$ needs to be defined first. The rest is then simple.